# Python replace string in Pandas column dataframe replace vs lambda

Tags: pandas, string, replace

Why these two are not the same:

```
df['REFERENCE'] =df['REFERENCE'].astype(str).str.strip().apply(lambda x:x.replace('(','')).apply(lambda x:x.replace(')',''))

df['REFERENCE'] =df['REFERENCE'].astype(str).str.strip().replace('(','')).replace(')',''))
```

The second one does not give error, but does not substitute '(' by ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['REFERENCE'].astype(str).str.strip().str.replace('(','')).str.replace(')',''))
```

a Pandas Series (column) has both a [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) method and a [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) replace method. The string accessor `.str` is necessary to use the string based methods which is what you're expecting.

*`Series.replace("foo", "bar")` looks in each cell of the Series, and if the value is equal to "foo" it is replaced with "bar". So for this method to work, a value in the Series must be exactly equal to "foo", nothing more, nothing less.

*`Series.str.replace("foo", "bar")` looks in each cell of the Series, and checks replaces ANY PART of the value that is "foo" with "bar". So in this case, the values inside the Series can be strings that simply contain the string "foo" and it will replace the portion of that string with "bar"

Comment: Sooooo good !!!! thanks. Real KEY ISSUE --> accesing the string of the cells!!!